# Android Firebase not Implementing Properly

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

In my **Project build.gradle** i added these lines

```
buildscript {
  ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        ...
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {  
        ...
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

and in my **app build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
//firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    ...
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

every thing is fine, gradle sync without warning or any errors, but am not able to use any of the *firebase-ads* library classes i can't find them it's like i never added that dependency even i manually types ***com.google.android.gms.*** and there is no package called ***ads***

even in .xml files i added an **AdView** when i press **Ctrl** and hover over the class name, all packages get highlighted untill **gms**, the **ads** and **adView** dosen't get highlighted.

[image: highlight]

i restarted Android studio,invalidate the cache, sync gradle with and without firebase-ads dependency, removed the library cache from .gradle file, nothing worked.... am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the solution was** to use an older version of firebase libraries '*9.0.2*' and it worked, thats still wierd i still want to know the real reason and if it was a bug in the libraries or Android studio to send a bug report

Answer (score 0):

You should also add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'` as a dependency. This is Firebase core dependency and should be added always.

Comment: i have it also still nothing happen, and the docs says nothing about that you should implement the core library in every use.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the option from Android Studio: Tools->Firebase and then you can choose the tool you want.

Comment: when i open it it tell me that my module app is already connected, i tried to reset every thing and use the tool only the same problem still, its like the new dependencies are empty or so